# Qt QMainWindow at Close

Tags: c++, qt

this may seem like a very simple question, but I want to dump some data whenever the `QMainWindow` closes, so I used the following piece of code:

```
QObject::connect(MainWindow.centralwidget, SIGNAL(destroyed()), this, SLOT(close()));
```

But this doesn't seem to make it call `close()`. Am I doing this wrong?.
 Isn't the centralwidget suppose to be destroyed?.

Or perhaps the application closes before `close()` can be called?.

Any other ways of doing it then?

Comment: Where does `this` fit in within your `QObject` hierarchy? It may be that it's getting deleted before the signal is sent. Of course I wouldn't worry about it too much as there are better alternatives in the answers given so far.

Comment: You cant dump data with the code you have shown... Also whether your question is how to dump data before QMainWindow closes? or why QMainwindow is not closing? Do make it clear...

Comment: I want to write and XML file after I click the 'x' to close the main window. It doesnt seem to work with the code above or the QApplication::lastWindowClosed() (or QApplication::aboutToQuit() for the matter)... Havent tried the QCloseEvent, but to keep the MVC structure, I rather not. The class I'm working in isnt the QMainWindow, rather I use files obtained by compiling ui files made in designer.

Comment: You can keep MVC by overriding closeEvent to emit a signal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd try [QGuiApplication::lastWindowClosed()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#lastWindowClosed) instead.

Comment: Didn't work, must mean it's being destroyed before that signal can be accepted? But that's odd because the class's destructor doesn't seem to be outputting anything (through std::cerr)

Comment: Make sure the object with the slot isn't a child of the QMainWindow. QWidgets destroy all their children when they go down.

Comment: @Cenoc: Post your `main` function, it can help clear up what is going on.

Comment: Woops, good catch, it worked! A million thanks! Definitely wouldnt have looked in the QApplication for this.

Answer (score 31):

You better to re implement one virtual function in your main `MainWindow` class like this:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {

    Q_OBJECT;

public:
    MainWindow();

protected:
     void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event);
}
```

and then declare in source file:

```
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event) {
     // do some data saves or something else
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: It's a good idea to complete the override. IE: in closeEvent() call QMainWindow::closeEvent(event); at the end of the function.  See the example in the documentation for the saveState() function here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html

Comment: While Ph0t0n isn't necessarily wrong, real-world `closeEvent()` implementations typically call either `event.accept()` or `event.ignore()` depending on whether unsaved changes exist or not. `QMainWindow::closeEvent(event)` is typically *not* called. See [`closeEvent()` documentation](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#closeEvent) for yet another useful example.

Answer (score 4):

Could you implement the [`closeEvent`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qwidget.html#closeEvent) function for your `QMainWindow` and put your code there?

Answer (score 3):

[image]
In Python (pyqt4 or pyqt5) you would need to do the following:

```
class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        #
        # My initializations...
        #

    ''''''

    def closeEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #
        # Stuff I want to do when this
        # just before (!) this window gets closed...
        #

    ''''''
```

It is interesting to know that the stuff in the **closeEvent(..)** function gets executed *just before*  the window closes. You can verify this with the following test:

```
    # Test if the closeEvent(..) function
    # executes just before or just after the window closes.
    def closeEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # 'self' is the QMainWindow-object.
        print(self)
        print(self.isVisible())

        # Print out the same stuff 2 seconds from now.
        QTimer.singleShot(2000, lambda: print(self))
        QTimer.singleShot(2100, lambda: print(self.isVisible()))

    ''''''
```

This is the output in your terminal:

```
<myProj.MyWindow object at 0x000001D3C3B3AAF8>
True

<myProj.MyWindow object at 0x000001D3C3B3AAF8>
False
```

This proves that the window was still visible when entering the **closeEvent(..)** function, but not after exiting that function.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial question and code don't match.  If you want to do something on the `QMainWindow` either create a sub-class and re-implement [`closeEvent`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qwidget.html#closeEvent) or connect to `MainWindow::destroyed()`.  See the 3rd paragraph for a note however.

But your code is showing what appears to be a 3rd class that is connecting a child of the `MainWindow` being destroyed to some slot called `close()`.  `centralwidget` will be destroyed AFTER MainWindow is already destroyed so this most likely won't help you anyway.

Also, this depends on how you created MainWindow (stack or heap) and if you are destructing it properly.  Ideally, you should create a subclass of `QMainWindow` (which if you used the designer you probably already have).

Answer (score 1):

Implement `QMainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *)` in your class. Then implement a new signal called `closing()` and emit it from your implementation of `QMainWindow::closeEvent()`. Then you can connect to that signal to do something right before the window is closed. You can also use `closeEvent` directly to do what you need to do, like save state, sync data or whatever.

Answer (score -2):

How about adding the dump code to your main windows' destructor?

Comment: You can't accesss I/O in destroyed or the destructor of the MainWindow - you are finally in your applications destructor and everything is destroyed. Use closeEvent() instead.